# PHP & PDO: placeholder results into wrong escaping with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, load-data-infile

I spent the last few hours in a paradox. I use this query to import a CSV file into my database.

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
        :file
    INTO TABLE
        product_feeds_raw
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY
        :fields_terminated_by
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY
        :fields_optionally_enclosed_by
    LINES TERMINATED BY
        :lines_terminated_by
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (
        `aaa`, 
        `bbb`
    )
    SET
        task_id = :task_id
');

$params = [

    'file' => $this->path_to_file,
    'fields_terminated_by' => $fields_terminated_by,
    'fields_optionally_enclosed_by' => $fields_optionally_enclosed_by,
    'lines_terminated_by' => $lines_terminated_by,
    'task_id' => $this->task_id
];

$query->execute($params);
```

The entire file with its settings (separator, enclosure, line termination etc.) arrives from an OAuth-based API from end-users. I am telling you this to underline that obviously I cannot trust user input hence I must use placeholders.

The problem is that the way PDO escapes such parameters is odd. This is what the user sends via API:

```
'fields_terminated_by' => ';',
'fields_optionally_enclosed_by' => '"',
'lines_terminated_by' => '\n',
```

In essence we have `;` `"` and `\n` which is pretty common for a CSV. I use these variables to feed my placeholders but PDO transforms them into this mess:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
    '../../myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE
    product_feeds_raw
FIELDS TERMINATED BY
    ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY
    '\"' <-------------- WRONG
LINES TERMINATED BY
    '\\n' <-------------- WRONG
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

As you can see PDO adds an unnecessary `\` in front of my `"`. Same goes for `\n` that becomes `\\n`. As result mysql fails to import the CSV because delimiters are different. The query should have been this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
    '../../myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE
    product_feeds_raw
FIELDS TERMINATED BY
    ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY
    '"' <-------------- CORRECT
LINES TERMINATED BY
    '\n' <-------------- CORRECT
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

I spent hours looking at other scripts but no one seems to use placeholders with `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Not for delimeters.

I know I could simply get rid of placeholders for delimiters and just use variables inside the query but I don't like this approach. Moreover I should rely on custom-made escapings to sanitize user-input.

Suggestions?

Comment: Escaping `"` shouldn't cause an issue; `'\"'` is exactly the same as `'"'`. The escaping of `\n` suggests to me that what is in `$lines_terminated_by` is actually `string(2) "\n"` rather than `string(1) "
"`. You should check via `var_dump` exactly what is in `$lines_terminated_by`

Comment: Nice catch! Yes, it's a `string(2)` but now I don't know what I am supposed to do. I should transform the `\n` provided via API into something... but what? `PHP_EOL` doesn't work.

Comment: `$lines_terminated_by = str_replace('\n', "\n", $lines_terminated_by)`?

Comment: I'm speachless. First thing first thank you. It solved the issue but I don't get how. Basically I am not replacing anything but just changing delimiters. Why does it work?

Comment: `'\n'` is the `string(2)` version, where `"\n"` is a newline character (note the different quotes). So now you should be getting `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` in your query.

Comment: Damn it! I must edit color scheme of my Visual Studio. Both versions of `\n` share the same color. They should have been different. I wasted so many hours just because I didn't notice it. Thanks again for your time.

p.s. If you trasform your comment into an answer, I can mark it as correct answer

Comment: It's not really worthy of an answer. I'd just delete the question as it will most probably just get closed as a typo or the like if someone reads all the comments

Comment: Anyway, glad I could help :)